# Validation of XML Signature and Digest Value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to SAML and I am trying to make a SAML and using that SAML I am trying to hit a service using XML Signature but I am not able do that.

Always I am getting a error "Failed to Validate SAML" generic error.

The error which I found in the logs are:

```
**Unable to verify elements(s):**

**Signature not valid. SignatureValue mismatched.#012#011Element**

#SamlAssertion-........25171a8731236r250b5f.......: Digest value mismatch: calculated: ..........
```

So can you tell me how can I make the valid SAML Resonse including valid Signature and Validate Digest Value.

My main concern is that is there any algorithm to generate the SAML Assertion Id and how can I calculate the Digest Value.

One more thing which I want to know is that is there any way through which I can validate the SAML Response.

For encoding part, I am using base64 encoder for encoding XML Signature.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="XYZ" Version="2.0">
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
   </saml2p:Status>
   <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="SamlAssertion-......3yAEvSQfRRrSPOGywx5....." IssueInstant="2016-05-03T13:35:35.350Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">04.HPS.FL*.381.712</saml2:Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#SamlAssertion-.......3yAEvSQfRRrSnG88XiBWCdo3k.....">
               <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                     <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/>
                  </ds:Transform>
               </ds:Transforms>
               <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
               <ds:DigestValue>......mXgkgVSfB+ah/WPD7Gd........</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
         </ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:SignatureValue>..w9+64O63tVe2Fe/CDp0Ptc15hfdqrc/Aav5Q3q5dUw+MLCbnMazoBU/4ryOrSqGU/LdjpuTNkJcSxycwTtCm4hYYyEpHKOwmh9OZbRBCZS+/RRB5OL5BPL7iM6DEWWexYbsEt/NPZah4U9qK/y0L1YJlMD6hOeHL33D2VWMSZt2qsxr2ycA==......</ds:SignatureValue>
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>........MIIFOzCCBCOgAwIBAgIJAOO4r8ltpPEkMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG0MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQMA4/ENiyHANrN6zXv05PH+leQb3p1EtRfXp3lEsSokfTJhz05EjjJu6RQVpKTNjLW+vR/6zinIELjwmr78iUoRAkQSMzTEa9rbytAFkpx7dNCaGp/fN7+fLSuGYMJ7g+O9E0nAxhqfAgMBAAGjggG+MIIBujAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwNwYDVR0fBDAwLjAsoCqgKIYmaHR0cDovL2NybC5nb2RhZGR5LmNvbS9nZGlnMnMxLTEyNC5jcmwwUwYDVR0gBEwwSjBIBgtghkgBhv1tAQcXATA5MDcGCCsGAQUFBwIBFitodHRwOi8vY2VydGlmaWNhdGVzLmdvZGFkZHkuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvMHYGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGowaDAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AuZ29kYWRkeS5jb20vMEAGCCsGAQUFBzAChjRodHRwOi8vY2VydGlmaWNhdGVzLmdvZGFkZHkuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvZ2RpZzIuY3J0MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFEDCvSeOzDSDMKIz1/tss/C0LIDOMDUGA1UdEQQuMCyCFSoudGVzdC5teXBsYW5saW5rLmNvbYITdGVzdC5teXBsYW5saW5rLmNvbTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUyUvEuGxt4ZxNXt71/lQe947AidcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAK2evMsrIK/s9wwEEGD/619lnthFxULsvo931NPqO0dHH1RsHSYFXnbV8EsZ+UzxKzhxxcn6JiqVgHYAfGV3xitTCfWF6L/k0Cmb3I3epnylJSGnttSejIa7STydgQeLRIlfXtbjBEI9aFHMpkFu2HwBFVYN+EwNFCKvVjhCLxw3zAXraWvHMuyBtvEu8LOfghJSSoxuFpwwKJw8YxpGxYewmZk7XOrmZMcwlHPlkkq6qIqTfPF/tD5w//6wRy1cRIyS3WzDtud1xMV9JMpT++FLdqi2qRT5NYXw4lDa/QtuTW/ajinqkzpBRLmrugLTkmoBUvJ9M1srFaAirli8mCw..........</ds:X509Certificate>
               <ds:X509SubjectName>CN=*.test.myplanlink.com, OU=Domain Control Validated</ds:X509SubjectName>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <saml2:Subject>
         <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">XYZ</saml2:NameID>
         <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:sender-vouches">
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">CN=*.test.myplanlink.com, OU=Domain Control Validated</saml2:NameID>
         </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml2:Subject>
      <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-05-03T13:35:35.408Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-05-10T13:35:35.350Z">
         <saml2:OneTimeUse/>
      </saml2:Conditions>

      <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-05-03T13:35:35.408Z" SessionIndex="abcdedf1234567" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2016-05-03T13:35:35.423Z">
         <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
             </saml2:AuthnContext>
          </saml2:AuthnStatement>
       </saml2:Assertion>
    </saml2p:Response>
```